# On a router, what decides if a packet should be forwarded or directed into the router itself?

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, router

I'm trying to learn how packet routing works on a linux-based router (OpenWRT in my case) a bit better for setting up a few projects/just-learning. Referencing the below chart, I'll break this into two questions

1. I'm wondering what (like a process, some other type of routing table, or something I can edit maybe?) is specifically responsible, outside of iptables, for making/directing the "Routing Decisions" in the nodes below. Note, I'm talking about the actual nodes labeled "Routing Decision" in the below picture, not the iptables. IE after a packet makes it through the nat PREROUTING, something has to tell the packet weather to next go to the input filter chain towards a local process, or go to the forward chains, right? For both parts of this question I'd say we can just stick to the top most "Routing Decision" node since I would guess the lower nodes encompass many more possibilities and processes.
2. Also/or, how is the decision made? Is it as simple as, if the incoming packet is destined for the interface ip it came in on (192.168.1.1 from the LAN connection for example), then it should go into this machine itself and send it through the input tables, otherwise it should get forwarded to another interface for going to the external network (just the internet in this case), so forward it to any other interface accepting forwarding. Or, are there other possible ways a packet could be directed into the router, to be handled by some process like a DNS server or something, instead of being directly forwarded to an internet-connected interface.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not an incoming packet should be routed to the local system is simply dependent on whether the destination IP address is one of the IP addresses on any interface of the local system. Note that it doesn't really matter on what interface a packet comes in; you can have an `eth0` interface with IP address `192.168.1.1`, and an extra IP address `192.168.1.2` on the `lo` interface: packets with destination address `192.168.1.2` arriving on `eth0` will be processed locally.

The routing decision is made according to the IP routing tables in conjunction with the IP routing rule tables. These tables are for a part automatically filled when IP addresses are set on interfaces.

You can view the routing rules with the `ip rule show` command (which can be abbreviated):

```
$ ip ru sh
    0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

You can inspect each of these routing tables with the `ip route show table xxx` command (can also be abbreviated). The `local` table concerns packets that should go to the local system:

```
$ ip ro sh table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.1.0 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
local 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope host  src 192.168.1.1 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

The `main` table is what you usually get to see when you e.g. use `route` (which is deprecated, just like `ifconfig`), so you don't have to specify its name:

```
$ ip ro sh
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

The `default` table is usually empty, but can be used to hold default routes e.g. if you have multiple gateways.

For more information read the [Policy Routing book](http://www.policyrouting.org/PolicyRoutingBook/)

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. The reference you gave also looks like a great central source being able to research these questions better on my own in the future.